# Reading or Writing multiple JSON objects to a single file

Tags: php, json

I have built a script to scrape some records and store them as a json object for later use. This is the last step in the scraping process (Area->Location->ReportMeta->**ReportDetails**) that are all working fine with this method of storing the data.

The issue is there are a lot of them, on the order of several hundred thousand. I tried accumulating them all into an array then encoding and writing that to a file, but it's maxing out memory before it gets close to being finished. I could up the memory but I am looking for a more stable/replicatable/"out of the box" way of doing this. Best practice if you will.

My first thought was just write them to the file as each one is scraped. That is working but I am left with a single file with many individual json objects which is nigh unreadable unless I do some special formatting to bring it back in.

I am looking for a better way of doing this, or some advice.

```
$reports_obj = new Report();
foreach($reports_array as $report){
    $report_details = $reports_obj->getReport($report['report_id'], $report['report_type']);
    $fp = fopen('report_details.json', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($report_details));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

This leaves me with a whole bunch of this:

```
{
  "report_id": "12345",
  "report_type": "Type A",
  "facility_name": "Name here",
  "facility_type": "building",
  "report_date": "26-February-2018"
}
{
  "report_id": "12345",
  "report_type": "Type A",
  "facility_name": "Name here",
  "facility_type": "building",
  "report_date": "26-February-2018"
}
{
  "report_id": "12345",
  "report_type": "Type A",
  "facility_name": "Name here",
  "facility_type": "building",
  "report_date": "26-February-2018"
}
```

Would it be best to try and find/replace the large file after the fact with proper json structure, or is there a better way of storing this? I can't open the file, re-read the data and then array push, for instance, as this would ultimately have the same limitation as just accumulating them all into an array to begin with.

As for "why" json? It's just a soft preference. I would like to stay with it if possible.

Comment: "Several hundred thousand" is a lot of data points to be working with a flat file if you want to work with the data. You should look into a database. The data looks well structured so SQL should handle it, or you could use a document store.

Comment: I will move it to a database eventually, the problem is that in the processing of scraping it, each of those records is an individual page request. I wanted to get it out and into a flat file to work with before running the import into a database.

Comment: Writing to a db shouldn't be any worse than writing to a file. If you want it in a db at some point and you're not going to do anything with the file, I'd just write it straight to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe , you can try this :

```
$reports_obj = new Report();
foreach($reports_array as $report){
  $report_details[] = $reports_obj->getReport($report['report_id'],$report['report_type']);
}
$jsonjson=json_encode($report_details);
$report="{\"report\":".$jsonjson."}";
$fp = fopen('report_details.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp,$report);
fclose($fp);
```

if you have , sample, maybe i can check ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a NoSQL database.

If you dont want/cant for what ever reason it is better to Loop through all reports, generate the JSON and write after instead of opening and closing a file each time

```
$result="";
   foreach($reports_array as $report){
    $report_details = $reports_obj->getReport($report['report_id'], $report['report_type']);
   $result .= json_encode($report_details)."\n\r";
}
$fp = fopen('report_details.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp,$result);
fclose($fp)
```